# Saving data in sessionStorage as undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Im saving the address data in the sessionstorage but it shows undefined where other data are saving fine and im able to retrive the data also.can anyone suggest what is the problem here

```
helper service
 /**ENCRYPT the value */
  encryptValue(data: string) {
    if (data)
      return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data.trim(), environment.ENC_SECRET_KEY.trim());
  }

  /**DECRYPT the value */
  decryptValue(data: string) {
    if (data)
      return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.trim(), environment.ENC_SECRET_KEY.trim()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
  }
```

```
login component
 /** store user INFO **/
  private _storeUserInfo(data) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("token", this.helper.encryptValue(data["access_token"].trim()));
    sessionStorage.setItem("mm-eml", this.helper.encryptValue(data["email"].trim()));
    sessionStorage.setItem("id", this.helper.encryptValue(data["id"]));
    sessionStorage.setItem("username", this.helper.encryptValue(data["username"]));
    sessionStorage.setItem("tenant_id", this.helper.encryptValue(data["tenant"]));
    sessionStorage.setItem("address",this.helper.encryptValue(data["address"]));
  }
```

im calling it in the another module

```
helper service

  /** DECRYPT the email */
  getEmail() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('mm-eml')) {
      return this.decryptValue(sessionStorage.getItem('mm-eml').trim());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  /** DECRYPT the user-id */
  getUserId() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('id')) {
      return this.decryptValue(sessionStorage.getItem('id'));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

    /** DECRYPT the user-id */
    getUserName() {
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('username')) {
        return this.decryptValue(sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };

  /** DECRYPT the tenant-id */
  getTenantId() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('tenant_id')) {
      return this.decryptValue(sessionStorage.getItem('tenant_id'));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
 /** DECRYPT the location-address */
 getLocationAddress() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('address')) {
    return this.decryptValue(sessionStorage.getItem('address'));
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

everything is fine except the address which shows undefined in session storage

Comment: Its better to store strings, I mean if you are storing object then stringify it before seting into the session storage

Answer (score 1):

For Example 
The [Web Storage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html) that `.getItem()` returns `null` for an unknown key.

Note however that `.getItem()` and `.setItem()` are specifically defined in the IDL as being the designated `getter` and `setter` for the **`Storage` interface**, and therefore they're also fully supported ways of accessing the contents of the storage.

However the `[]` syntax is more akin to a normal object and/or array property `getter`, and like those returns `undefined` for an unknown property name.

The reason not to use `[]` syntax is that it will operate on object properties first and will quite happily allow you to overwrite real properties and methods of the `localStorage` **`object`**, c.f:

For Eg:

```
> localStorage['address'] = function() { return 0 }
> localStorage.getItem('address')
0
```

---

## Second Example

In javascript you always get an `undefined` value for keys that does not exist inside an object.

```
a = {}; //new object
alert(a["address"]); // you get 'undefined' because "address" keys is not found
```

In localStorage `.getItem` is a method who does check keys inside the `localStorage` object and returns `null` if not found.

Don't blame **javascript**, it's just the `localStorage` object **behaviour**

---

under Helper Service put this code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor() {}
  createLocalStorage(key: string, value: any){
  console.log('value => '+value);
    var cryptoData : any = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, 'encoded data');
    sessionStorage.setItem(key,cryptoData);
  }

  getLocalStorage(key){
    var encodeData = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    if (encodeData) {
      var decodeData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encodeData, 'encoded data').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      return decodeData;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and localstorage setItem return `undefined.` [you can check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Comment: @ kiran  Mistry sorry i diidnt able to catch what you said.so you are asking to remove the [ ] syntax from setItem,If i do so im getting undefined

Comment: you are using `this.helper.encryptValue` for encrypt the value of localstorage

Comment: and because you are accessing a object thats why u not getting address key

Comment: @ kiren Mistry helper is a service where im having the encryptValue method

Comment: ya i know helper is your service and in that service `encryptValue` is your method

Comment: share your helper service code for encryption and decryption

Comment: edit your question don't share on comment plz...delete it from comment

Comment: i edited my question and shared the helper service also

Comment: check my answer in last localstorage setitem noting to return if you return then it will give you `undefined`

Comment: @ajay check my edit answer make helper service as in answer

Answer (score 1):

If the `address` is a JSON object then you have to store it as a string:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("address", JSON.stringify(this.helper.encryptValue(data["address"])));
```

To retrieve it:

```
var addressObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
```

One example:

```js
const address = {"Line1":"ABC, Satara", "Pin":"415013"};

const addressStringToStore = JSON.stringify(address);
console.log(addressStringToStore.Line1);
// its undefined

const originalObject = JSON.parse(addressStringToStore);
console.log(originalObject.Line1);
// expected output: ABC, Satara
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution, where i didnt properly bind the data to store in the session storage.